# rdoc, darkfish, and the :call-seq: tag

Tags: ruby, documentation, rdoc

I'm in the process of documenting a Ruby project with rdoc, and I discovered the darkfish rdoc formatter.  I really like it, but the `:call-seq:` tag no longer works.  Instead, it puts the literal string `:call-seq:` in the documentation and then formats the call sequence itself as a code block.  I don't want to just take all of the :call-seq: blocks out of my code, since much of my documentation needs to refer to instance names and parameter names given in the `:call-seq:` block.  Has anyone else had this problem?  What should I do, and is there a workaround?  I'm pretty sure the `:call-seq:` tag was working before when I was using the default formatter, but I can't be sure because I can't figure out how to go back to generating the original format (calling rdoc with no arguments except files generates darkfish output now, even if I delete the doc folder!)  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Which version of rdoc are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I strongly recommend moving from rdoc to [YARD](http://yardoc.org/). It doesn't support the old call-seq itself, but instead it has tags and especially the [@overload](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#overload) tag will superiorly replace call-seq. All the documentation on [rubydoc.info](http://rubydoc.info/) is also generated using YARD.

Here's the example for @overload from the YARD documentation:

```
# @overload set(key, value)
#   Sets a value on key
#   @param [Symbol] key describe key param
#   @param [Object] value describe value param
# @overload set(value)
#   Sets a value on the default key `:foo`
#   @param [Object] value describe value param
def set(*args)
end
```