# Yard and C extension

Tags: ruby, yard, ruby-c-extension

I have a C ruby extension that I document with rdoc. There are both C files and ruby files that are parsed by rdoc.

Does yard can do the same and is there an "easy way", (I mean a commonly used way) to migrate from rdoc to yard?

Comment: Yes Yard can document C files. Can you show a sample of your current C docs? What have you looked at so far towards the conversion? Are you sure you even need to convert anything, Yard is an extension of rdoc . . . have you simply tried to render your current docs using `yardoc`?

Comment: Yes I tryed `yardoc` in the main directory ( https://github.com/cedlemo/ruby-clangc ) but whithout success, I use rake rdoc in order to generate my documentation, you can see the Rake file in the link I give you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Neil Slater said, **Yard** can parse **rdoc** style documentation with one exception which is the `:call-seq` tag from **rdoc**. Its equivalent is `@overload` from **Yard**. (see [rdoc, darkfish, and the :call-seq: tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934008/rdoc-darkfish-and-the-call-seq-tag))

For me I used a Rake task in order to generate the rdoc documentation:

```
require "rdoc/task"

RDOC_FILES = FileList["README.rdoc", "ext/clangc/clangc.c", "ext/clangc/constants.c", "ext/clangc/class_Index.c", "ext/clangc/class_TranslationUnit.c", "lib/clangc.rb"]

Rake::RDocTask.new do |rd|
  rd.main = "README.rdoc"
  rd.rdoc_dir = "doc"
  rd.rdoc_files.include(RDOC_FILES)
end
```

I just have to launch `rake rdoc`

In order to use **Yard** instead, I just have to create a Rake task like this:

```
require "yard"
YARD_FILES = FileList["ext/clangc/clangc.c", "ext/clangc/class_Index.c", "ext/clangc/class_TranslationUnit.c", "lib/clangc.rb"]

YARD::Rake::YardocTask.new do |t|
  t.files   = YARD_FILES   # optional
  t.options = %w(-o yard_documentation --readme README.rdoc) # optional
end
```

Then I use `rake yard`. There still are some errors but the this is a good begining.